# How to point GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to a json file stored in an S3 Bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform

I have my credentials stored in an S3 bucket and can access the file using the boto3 library but how can I point`os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']` to the file stored in S3

```
client = boto3.client(
    "s3",
    aws_access_key_id=access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key
)

credentials = client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key='name-of-file.json')
GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS = json.loads(credentials["Body"].read().decode('utf-8'))

# THIS DOES NOT WORK
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS
```

Comment: No, you cannot set the environment variable with the JSON contents. The Python SDK accepts a JSON string. Example: **service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info()**

Comment: Where are you running your code? On AWS?